# Implementing a back button in android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, back-button, softkeys

I'm in the process of creating a set of home/back keys for when the statusbar in android is hidden. I've designed a button that simulates a home-key press as such

```
private void InjectKey(final int keyEventCode) {
       new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
               new Instrumentation().sendKeyDownUpSync(keyEventCode);
        }
       }).start();
```

}

which works just fine for home-key presses. However, when I try to apply the same solution to the back button, the app obviously just calls finish() on itself.

My question is this: How do I implement the backbutton so that it calls "back" on the latest app and on itself?

Thanks!

Comment: check this out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Answer (score 0):

In second activity if you uses your own back button,
and uses finish(); to stop that activity
then following method will be called.
so override folloing method in your Second Activity
and put needed code in it

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "STOP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

In the Second Activity, you can use Override following method
Which will be called when back button is called

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "BACK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            super.onBackPressed(); // allows standard use of backbutton for page 1
    }
```

Put needed code in this method.